Flutter: fix bottom overflow
I arranged the elements symmetrically in pairs. I added 6 cards for scrolling, but there was a problem. And also when you click on search. Please help me, I do not know how to fix this enter image description hereenter image description here
Here is the code I wrote for the cards
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [ 
        GridView.builder(        
          itemCount: categoryList.length, 
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics:  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {       
            return CategoryCard(
             category: categoryList[index],
            );
          },
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 25,
            vertical: 30,
          ),
          gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 0.75,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 24,
         ),
        ), 
      ],  
    );
  }
  

The parent widget. Maybe the problem is with him
class CategoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Category category;
  const CategoryCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.category,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const CourseScreen(),
        ),
      ),
   
      child: Container(
        
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
              blurRadius: 5.0,
              spreadRadius: .15,
            ),
             //BoxShadow
          ],
        ),

        child: Column(
          
          children: [     
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Image.asset(
                category.thumbnail,
                height: kCategoryCardImageSize,
              ),
            ),
            
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
              
            ),
            
            Text(category.name),
            Text(
              "${category.noOfCourses} ",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    
    );
  }
}


Just remove the Column widget and use the GridView directly
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(        
          itemCount: categoryList.length, 
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics:  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {       
            return CategoryCard(
             category: categoryList[index],
            );
          },
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 25,
            vertical: 30,
          ),
          gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 0.75,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 24,
         ),
    );

or , use the Expanded widget.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: categoryList.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CategoryCard(
              category: categoryList[index],
            );
          },
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 25,
            vertical: 30,
          ),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 0.75,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 24,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}



Using the first option did not solve the problem.
If I use the second option, it gives an error: "Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded."

hmm the problem should be related to the parent widget, can you update your question adding the code that calls this widget?

I added the parent widget

if you replace "  return CategoryCard(
category: categoryList[index],
);"  with a Text(" widget , does it work? otherwise you should add the widget above your "Body" widget to check what's happening

I found the problem. I built the elements on the page incorrectly. Instead of   body: Сolumn()
I wrote body: ListView()
Thank you so much for your help)

If the solution didn't fix your problem and you have found something else, why did you marked is as accepted answer?

You need to remove Column widget, and physics and shrinkWrap
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: categoryList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CategoryCard(
          category: categoryList[index],
        );
      },
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 25,
        vertical: 30,
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 0.75,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        mainAxisSpacing: 24,
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is the best solution, but you can also just add and Expanded as a parent of GridView.builder
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: categoryList.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CategoryCard(
                category: categoryList[index],
              );
            },
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 25,
              vertical: 30,
            ),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 0.75,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              mainAxisSpacing: 24,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

